# Why is a part of the connection disconnected when tcp connection number is up to 1000?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, client-server, tcp

I write two program using socket. The server listens on a port. And it will open a thread for a connection. Client sends a connection.

When I run server and client locally, I can create 5000 connections. However, when I put the server program on the cloud server, I use watch `ss -s` to see the connection number of tcp. During the process of establishing 5000 connections, some of the connections will be closed automatically.

Even if I only set up 1300 connections, some tcp connections will also be closed. I have used the `ulimit -n 65536` command to open the number of local and remote threads to 65536.
And this result is unstable, it is possible that out of the next 1300 connections, only 500 will succeed, while 800 will fail....

Why would this happen? Is this because of the speed of the Internet? Or is it because of too many threads? But my test on the local is no problem

The following is the result of the `watch ss -s` command:

```
TCP:   1310 (estab 953, closed 348, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), 
ports
0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         0         -         -
RAW       0         0         0
UDP       10        7         3
TCP       962       959       3
INET      972       966       6
FRAG      0         0         0
```

Comment: What language are you using?
Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I use c language coding my socket program in Ubuntu. And the code is a little long

Comment: I guess it is going to be complicated to help you, then

Comment: Too many threads, because stack memory is limited. Maybe for security reasons in your cloud environment stronger than on your local machine. Rethink your desing and move away from one thread per connection.

Comment: Improved readability

Comment: With multiple threads, a race condition is always possible, but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing the code.